# How do I find the closest match to a time that I specify down a column of hh:mm:ss, that is sampling 24 hours a day?

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

My sampling records a set of data every 5, 6 or 7 seconds, depending on the return data. So If use the, Find All, approach to find for example 6:00:00, and there was a reading at 6:00:00 (6:00 AM), I would get in return the address of the row that 6:00:00 was on, and if there was a reading at 18:00:00 (6:00 PM), I would also get that address returned. The problem is that if there is not a sampling at exactly 6:00:00 or 18:00:00, I get nothing. 
What I'm looking for is a way to get two addresses per day returned to create a per day range between those two addresses. If I specify 6:00:00, but there is a 5:59:58 on one line, followed on the next row with 6:00:03, I would like to be able to capture the address of the 5:59:58 time stamp. Then again at 18:00:00, (6:00 PM), if not exactly 18:00:00, then the closest as described above. So in the end I would end up with a set of addresses per day, to put together as a Range. 
If the first sampling at the beginning of the data set starts after my specified time, then whatever that time is, will be the first days start time. Likewise, if the last sampling time of the data set ends before the specified time, then the last time stamp will be the last days stop time. I hope someone can advise. The coding that I have tried is:

```
Sub find_All_2()

    'This macro finds all cells containing "6:00:00" in Range("C:C")
    '
    'This works to find 6:00:00 and places the address in the Immediate window.
    '$C$30416
    '$C$38240
    '$C$45890
    '$C$53694
    '$C$61357
    '$C$84640
    '$C$92292, row 100095 has 18:00:02, and misses it because its not 6:00:00
    '$C$161331
    'However, if I search for 7:00:00, this macro only finds 2
    '$C$77468, because all of the others are not exactly 7:00:00.
    '$C$139112
    '

    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddr As String
    With Range("C:C")
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.count)
    End With
    Set FoundCell = Range("C:C").Find(what:="7:00:00", after:=LastCell)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
    End If
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    Debug.Print FoundCell.Address
    Set FoundCell = Range("C:C").FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
'
End Sub
```

Comment: From what I can see you are currently searching for a `string` that represents your time value, have you tried searching for the time value instead?

Comment: Samuel Everson, Thank you for looking at my inquiry. I have been thinking of different things that I might try. I'm really not a vba programmer per se, I found this bit of code and am trying to bend it to my way of thinking, however crude that may be. So because I placed into the Find, what:="7:00:00", the 7:00:00 inside of parenthesis, that is making my search a "String" search. So does this mean that if I were to search instead for: Find(what:=7/24, that this would make it a time search, using the Time Serial Number? I'll try it.

Comment: I tried modifying the Find line to: <Set FoundCell = Range("C:C").Find(what:=6 / 24, after:=LastCell)> This modification didn't return anything, and went straight to the end without finding anything. Is this what you meant by searching for a Time Value instead? I am also looking at that <(after:=FoundCell)>, component, and thinking that since 'FoundCell' is a variable, does this mean I can replace the 'what' component, what:="7:00:00", to a variable, without the enclosed parenthesis, like: what:=someVariable, that finds the closest value. Any thoughts?

Comment: In Excel time and date values are represented by a number which is then formated as time/date. Yo see examples of this, type a date or time into a cell on your sheet and change the formatting to `Number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, c As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set c = ClosestTimeCell(rng, "06:30")
    Debug.Print c.Address, Format(c.Value, "hh:mm:ss")

    Set c = ClosestTimeCell(rng, "18:30")
    Debug.Print c.Address, Format(c.Value, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub

'return the cell in rng with the closest match to the provided time
Function ClosestTimeCell(rng As Range, theTime As String) As Range
    Dim diffs, pos
    'Get all the absolute differences from the desired time
    '  Returns an array of values (evaluated as an array formula)
    diffs = rng.Parent.Evaluate("ABS(" & rng.Address & "-TIMEVALUE(""" & theTime & """))")
    'get the position of the smallest difference
    pos = Application.Match(Application.Min(diffs), diffs, 0)
    Set ClosestTimeCell = rng.Cells(pos)
End Function
```

EDIT - after seeing source file...

Array formula approach:

[image]

VBA approach:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, rngDays As Range, rngTimes As Range
    Dim startTime, endTime, numDays, dict As Object, data()
    Dim startD, endD, k, bFirst As Boolean
    Dim days, times, i As Long, d, t, currentDay, n As Long, v, indx As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngDays = ws.Range("B1:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    startTime = ws.Range("H2").Value
    endTime = ws.Range("I2").Value

    days = rngDays.Value
    times = rngDays.Offset(0, 1).Value

    'get the unique days to assess
    'we started from row 1 to avoid offsets, so ignore the headers...
    For i = 2 To UBound(days, 1)
        If Not dict.exists(days(i, 1)) Then dict.Add days(i, 1), dict.Count + 1
    Next i

    'use this for tracking start/end time differences (col 1 and 3)
    '  and row numbers with smallest deltas (cols 2 and 4)
    ReDim data(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 4)

    For i = 2 To UBound(days, 1)
        indx = dict(days(i, 1)) '>>  "row" in 2-D tracking array
        bFirst = IsEmpty(data(indx, 1)) 'first row for this day?

        t = times(i, 1)
        startD = CDbl(Abs(t - startTime)) 'start delta
        endD = CDbl(Abs(t - endTime))     'end delta

        'compare, and track smallest deltas and row numbers
        If bFirst Or startD < data(indx, 1) Then
            data(indx, 1) = startD
            data(indx, 2) = i
        End If
        If bFirst Or endD < data(indx, 3) Then
            data(indx, 3) = endD
            data(indx, 4) = i
        End If

    Next i

    'print each day and "best match" start/end time rows
    For Each k In dict
        Debug.Print k, data(dict(k), 2), data(dict(k), 4)
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: To Tim Williams, thanks for your suggested code. I ran your suggested piece of code and got a: Run-Time error 5: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument, on line: <Set ClosestTimeCell = rng.Cells(pos)>, in the function, ClosestTimeCell.

Comment: What is the value of `pos` when it fails?  I did test this, and it was working OK for me....

Comment: Thanks Tim Williams. In the Locals Window, both the diffs and the pos variables show a Error 2015 of the Variant/Error Type. Some information found here: [link](https://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/error-2015-using-application-evaluate-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Does the range you're passing in contain only time values, and is it a single column?

Comment: It's all time readings except the heading. Here's a sample: Time
6:54:15
6:54:20
6:54:26
6:54:31
6:54:37
6:54:43
6:54:48
6:54:54
6:55:00
6:55:05
6:55:12
6:55:18
6:55:23
6:55:29
6:55:34
6:55:40
It goes on like this 24 hours a day. This particular data file goes on for 14 days, 12 hours, 13 minutes and 18 seconds.

Comment: So you have multiple days in one column?  Does that mean you need multiple ranges, one per day?  And if there are only time values, how to tell which day is which?

Comment: Tim Williams, I modified your code just a bit. First made it Dim my Worksheet. Then most recent tweak, Changed the Set rng to my Column (“C2:C”. When I originally modified your code, to my column, I inadvertently left it as C1:C. Now the error is different. diffs is no longer giving the same error and has the value, diffs 1.6840277777 of type Variant/Double. pos now has Error 2042 of type Variant /Error

Comment: Tim Williams, Thanks again for your following this issue. Yes, that is correct. I have another data set with over a month of data. This one that I'm working on just happens to be 14 days plus.  What I'm looking for is a way to get two addresses per day returned to create a per day range between those two addresses. I do have a Day Column and a Date Column that I could use if I need to. I didn't think that I need to. This is how I started down the road of using the FindAll, but quickly found out that I have some reading where I'm looking to capture 6:00:00 AM and 6:00:00 PM, but there are none.

Comment: Can you share a workbook containing just the column of time values?  Via Dropbox/Box/GoogleDrive/Onedrive etc

Comment: Instead, I'm seeing 5:59:58, 6:00:03, which Excel completely misses. This is why I'm trying to find the closest time to 6:00:00 AM and the closest time to 6:00:00 PM for EACH day.

Comment: Sure, I'm not quite sure how to do that though, and this file has 223,675 rows.

Comment: With only the relevant columns it shouldn't be unmanageable  - you can always remove some of the rows - as long as there are a few day's worth of times that should be enough for testing.

Comment: Tim Williams, I have copied a a section from start to the end of the third day into a single sheet Excel file. It is 5 95 MB. Is that too big? Or should I whittle it down to whatever size will work for you. Thanks Steve

Comment: 5.95 or 595 ?  5.95 is fine but 595 probably too big.

Comment: Five Point Nine Five Mega Bytes. It's currently sitting on my desktop. Tell me how to get it to you for your perusal.

Comment: Tim Williams, Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Upon testing (and some learning) I ended working a solution that sort of contradicted my previous answer, so here is what I came up with.

```
Option Explicit

Option Explicit

Sub find_All_2()
Dim LastUsedRow As Long
Dim FirstCell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim myDayRange As Range
Dim InputTime As String
Dim CellToCheck As Variant
Dim TimeVal As Variant
Dim TimeToEvaluate As String
Dim SecondsCounter As Single

InputTime = FormatNumber("12:00:02", 5)

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastUsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For CellToCheck = LastUsedRow To 1 Step -1
        If LastCell Is Nothing Then
            TimeVal = Split(FormatNumber(.Range("C" & CellToCheck).Value, 5), ".")
            If Format("0." & TimeVal(1), "0.00000") = InputTime Then
                Set LastCell = .Cells(CellToCheck, 3)
                Exit For
            Else
                For SecondsCounter = -0.00008 To 0.00008 Step 0.00001
                    SecondsCounter = Round(SecondsCounter, 5)
                    TimeToEvaluate = CDec("0." & TimeVal(1)) + SecondsCounter
                    If Format(TimeToEvaluate, "0.00000") = InputTime Then
                        Set LastCell = .Cells(CellToCheck, 3)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next SecondsCounter
            End If
        End If
    Next CellToCheck

    If LastCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No LastCell Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

     For CellToCheck = LastCell.Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If FirstCell Is Nothing Then
            TimeVal = Split(FormatNumber(.Range("C" & CellToCheck).Value, 5), ".")
            If Format("0." & TimeVal(1), "0.00000") = InputTime Then
                Set FirstCell = .Cells(CellToCheck, 3)
                Exit For
            Else
                For SecondsCounter = -0.00006 To 0.00008 Step 0.00001
                    SecondsCounter = Round(SecondsCounter, 5)
                    TimeToEvaluate = CDec("0." & TimeVal(1)) + SecondsCounter
                    If Format(TimeToEvaluate, "0.00000") = InputTime Then
                        Set FirstCell = .Cells(CellToCheck, 3)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next SecondsCounter
            End If
        End If
    Next CellToCheck

    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No FirstCell Found"
    Else
        Set myDayRange = .Range(FirstCell.Address & ":" & LastCell.Address)
        Debug.Print "The Range from " & Format(FirstCell, "hh:mm:ss") & " to " & Format(LastCell, "hh:mm:ss") & " is: "; myDayRange.Address
    End If

    End With
End Sub
```

In short, it formats the input value as a number and the input is then compared against the numeric value of each cell in the range (within the `For...Loop` criteria.)

If an exact match isn't found it then loops through - 7 to + 7 seconds of the input time to find the nearest match.

I'm sure it could be refined but from my brief testing this output a range as I expected.

Comment: Samuel Everson, Thank you for the piece of code that you provided. I tested it as you sent it, except changing to my ‘sheetname’, searching for:
Doing a search for 6:00:00 converts to 0.25000 and returns: The Range from 05:59:58 to 06:00:03 is: $C$215191:$C$215192. This particular data set is 14 days, 12 hours, 13 minutes and 18 seconds. So I need at least 14 Range sets, maybe 15.

Comment: Well that's a whole other kettle of Fish. If I have some time later on Today I'll have a look into it. I also noticed from the comments on Tim's answer there is also a Date column.You might consider updating your question to include such information including *what you actually want to achieve* as this is unclear from your original question.

Comment: Thanks Samuel Everson for the followup. Sorry for not being as clear from the get go. Here's a quick summary: I built a solar project with an automatic transfer switch that I have connected to one circuit in my house. I sample and capture details of many aspects of its operation including battery charge controller, battery charge and discharge and condition. I also monitor power consumption of the grid circuit and inverter circuit, with time and temperature. I take a sampling every 5 to 7 seconds, depending on the data returned. I'm not an Excel vba programmer and need a little help.

Comment: I wish to chart this data and make a retrievable history. This is my entertainment.